# Single monitor working as multiple

Tags: display

I have a multiple setups with 6 monitors, but would like to explore using 1 monitor/tv but act like 6 monitors. (i.e. you max a window it does not go over the whole screen just one of the 6 sections). Please let me know what info you need any i will be happy to give what is needed.

Comment: unclear what you're asking

Comment: You should certainly tell us which OS you are using.

Answer (score 0):

[This might be what you're looking for](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc817881).  You can have multiple "Desktops" in one monitor/window.